# Volume of pyramid where we know the sides

Tags: volume

A triangular pyramid has five sides of length $2$, and another side of length $\sqrt6$.
What is the volume of the pyramid?

[image: pyramid diagram]

Comment: Found what?​​​​

Comment: volume of pyramid...

Comment: he is new , his writing is wrong, but this is quite interesting question

Comment: I am new, what is wrong ?

Comment: [Tetrahedron: Heron-type formula for the volume of a tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Heron-type_formula_for_the_volume_of_a_tetrahedron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the middle of $SC$. Then $|SM| = |MC| = 1$

Because $|AC| = |AS|$, we have that $AMS$ is a right triangle, so by the Pythagorean theorem we have $|AM| = \sqrt{|AS|^2 - |MS|^2} = \sqrt{2^2 - 1} = \sqrt3$, similarly $|BM| = \sqrt3$.

But then $|AM|^2 + |BM|^2 = 3 + 3 = 6 = |AB|^2$, so by the converse of the Pythagorean theorem the triangle $AMB$ is right.

So the volume can be calculated as (base $ACS$ and height $MB$) $$V = \frac13\cdot\frac12|CS||MA|\cdot|MB| = \frac16\cdot2\cdot\sqrt3\cdot\sqrt3 = \frac13\cdot3 = 1$$

Comment: Why V= 1/3(|CS|⋅1/2|MA||MB|) ...

I know, V= 1/3 Sb x h = 1/3 (b x l / 2) x SO

Comment: @user2685833 Well I calculate it as a sum of 2 pyramids, _MABS_ and _MABC_, each with height $\frac12|CS|$, so the sum of heights is $|CS|$. But you could also calculate it as a pyramid with base _ACS_ and height _MB_ like this: $\frac13(\frac12|MA||CS|\cdot|MB|)$ which gives the same result. That's probably easier.